# How to decrypt node AES encryption in php?

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, aes, crypt

I have code written in node.js:

```
var encodeKey = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(pass, 'utf-8').digest();
var cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', encodeKey, iv);
console.log(cipher.update(text, 'hex', 'utf8') + cipher.final('utf8'));
```

i have `text`, `pass` and `iv` vars. When i try translate this code into PHP, i have different results. This is PHP code:

```
$encodeKey = hash('sha256', $pass);
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($text, 'aes-256-cbc', $encodeKey, 0, $iv);
```

Where is the bug? Thanks a lot for any suggestion!

Comment: Are your encodeKeys the same?

Comment: yes, all variables are the same

Answer (score 0):

Your JS code...

```
var encodeKey = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(pass, 'utf-8').digest();
```

...and your PHP code...

```
$encodeKey = hash('sha256', $pass);
```

Are not the same. They're producing different keys, which will result in different encryption.

Try this instead:

```
$encodeKey = hash('sha256', $pass, true);
```

However, this is only part of the problem.

- AES-CBC is [vulnerable to chosen-ciphertext attacks](https://robertheaton.com/2013/07/29/padding-oracle-attack/).
- IVs should be randomly generated per message, not held constant. (It isn't clear from your code if this is static or not.)

Recommendation: Switch to [Sodium-Plus](https://github.com/paragonie/sodium-plus) (JS) and [ext/sodium](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium) (PHP).

If you upgrade PHP to 7.2 or newer, you should get libsodium for free. Otherwise, [sodium_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/sodium_compat) will do the trick.